# MySql lower_case_table_names = 2 in Azure but MySql Workbench say it's = 1

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, mysql-workbench

I have created a MqSql v5.7 database on Azure and set the `lower_case_table_names` property to 2, to enable support for uppercase tablenames.

I have downloaded and installed the MySql Workbench v6.3.9 CE x64 edition and connected to my Azure MySql database.

I created a new schema name ecommerce and started creating a new table named Product. When I attempted to apply the change, I received the following error:-

**Error Message**

> The server is configured with lower_case_table_names=1, which only
>   allows lowercase characters in schema and table names. The object will
>   be created as 'product'.

The value of the `lower_case_table_names` property reported in the Azure portal is different to the property value reported in MySql Workbench.

**Azure MySql Configuration**
[image: Azure Portal]

**MySql Workbench Configuration**
[image: MySql Workbench]

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

For Azure Database for MySQL, In MySQL 8.0, `lower_case_table_name` is set to `1` **by default**, and you can't change it.

Comment: thanks @bluetata
Did you find that in some online documentation? If so could you please include the link.

Comment: @MrSlim Please refer to the Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-server-parameters#lower_case_table_names

Comment: Just to add more info: with Terraform I got this error --> Code="ConfigurationReadOnly" Message="The configuration(s) 'lower_case_table_names' is(are) read-only for MySQL server version 8.0.21."

Answer (score 0):

The value MySQL Workbench shows comes directly from server variables. You can even run the query yourself:

[image]

If that still shows 1 then the value on the Azure website is plain wrong. I assume you double checked you are on the correct connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I executed your query in MySql Workbench and the lower_case_table_names property returned 1. I only have 1x connection, 1x MySql instance (azure) and 1x schema. I read other articles which indicated that after changing lower_case_table_names (or other variables) the MySql instance should be restarted. I cannot see where an Azure  MySql instance can be restarted.

Comment: I'd contact a support person to solve this contradiction. Something is obviously different to what they say.

Comment: In my case Azure is returning `lower_case_table_names 0`

Comment: @juanmah What does MySql Workbench report the value as being?

Comment: `lower_case_file_system OFF` and `lower_case_table_names 0` for both MySQL Workbench report and 'show VARIABLES' query

Comment: If you set lower_case_table_names = 0 in Azure, is it reflected in MySql workbench

Comment: @MrSlim I am having the same issue. Setting it to 2 in Azure, MySQL Workbench shows 1 and I have no idea where to restart. Did you find out how to solve this?

Comment: @DavideDeSantis I am afraid not. I ended up moving away from MySQL and used Table Storage for my requirements. Please post an answer if you manage to resolve this issue though. Good luck!